# Best way to store a List of GUID and DateTime objects

Tags: c#

I need to store a C# list of pair values GUID and Datetime.

The list will be static and I wanted to be able to quickly retrieve the existence of a GUID value so speed is essential.

What's the best alternative between list, dictionary or any other searchable collection for GUID's keys?

Comment: You want to have `Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>` ?, why `Guid` as key ?

Comment: Here is a performance Test ... http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/

Comment: @Habib Guid is the TokenKey generated by the DB so that's my current key. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @Mansfield it's the Authentication Token GUID so could run in the 10,000s concurrent ...or more

Comment: @Johnny, No its not a problem , its perfectly fine, I wasn't sure about your question and that is why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable

Based on experience, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is all around the fastest/easiest way.

Comment: Looking up a key in a `SortedDictionary` is O(log n) in `Dictionary` it is "almost" O(1). Looking up a Value is O(n) in both cases. So if lookup speed is most essential one should actually use `Dictionary` - not `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: You are right, I got the Big O's mixed up while typing. Updating answer

Answer (score 5):

I'd just use a `Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>`. I'd be surprised if there was any major performance difference between using a dictionary or list, for example. I'd see how the dictionary performs and then try something else if you're finding it slow before trying to micro-optimize before you even know if it'll be a problem.